# D3 selection causing incomprehensibely overlapping line plots---how do I fix it?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am trying to draw a path on a `Leaflet` map using a `D3` overlay, via the [Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay) utility library.

I inspected the output of the routing functions that I wrote using `mplleaflet` in Python, and got very neat output ([responsible block](http://bl.ocks.org/ResidentMario/01ba041e3cdf69662311792ca9f6aea8)).

I wrote a `D3` thing that ought to get the same output. However I instead got a very jagged line, which, on closer visual inspection, turned out to be several lines intertwined in a weird way:

[image]

Changing the plot to one of circles instead of of a path shows that this is due to some sort of strangely arrayed points:

[image]

You can try out the responsible code yourself [in this block](http://bl.ocks.org/ResidentMario/raw/13e902fd16fca628cc3fc826600bd2fe/).

Yet in both cases (the mplleaflet plot that works and the D3 plot that doesn't) I am merely trying to plot the same exact series of coordinates:

```
[[-73.98208, 40.76529], [-73.98225, 40.76476], [-73.98232, 40.76457], [-73.98238, 40.76441], [-73.98239, 40.76438], [-73.98241, 40.76434], [-73.98245, 40.76423], [-73.98249, 40.76412], [-73.98252, 40.76405], [-73.98254, 40.76402], [-73.98257, 40.76396], [-73.98281, 40.76351], [-73.98288, 40.76339], [-73.98293, 40.7633], [-73.983, 40.76318], [-73.98321, 40.76282], [-73.98326, 40.76273], [-73.98332, 40.76264], [-73.9836, 40.76219], [-73.98368, 40.76207], [-73.98387, 40.76178], [-73.98411, 40.76145], [-73.98452, 40.7608], [-73.98456, 40.76072], [-73.98465, 40.76052], [-73.98487, 40.76013], [-73.98487, 40.76013], [-73.98453, 40.75999], [-73.98418, 40.75984], [-73.98418, 40.75984], [-73.98441, 40.75952], [-73.98461, 40.7592], [-73.98507, 40.75858], [-73.98526, 40.75833], [-73.98553, 40.75796], [-73.98568, 40.75778], [-73.986, 40.75734], [-73.98648, 40.7567], [-73.98695, 40.75603], [-73.98695, 40.75603], [-73.98644, 40.75582], [-73.98644, 40.75582], [-73.98668, 40.75505], [-73.98691, 40.75434], [-73.98713, 40.75362], [-73.98723, 40.75332], [-73.98732, 40.75303], [-73.98735, 40.75291], [-73.98754, 40.75218], [-73.98761, 40.75187], [-73.98762, 40.75183], [-73.98771, 40.75145], [-73.98774, 40.7512], [-73.98783, 40.7507], [-73.98789, 40.75036], [-73.98798, 40.74988], [-73.98804, 40.74968], [-73.98809, 40.74957], [-73.98814, 40.74948], [-73.9883, 40.74925], [-73.9883, 40.74924], [-73.98829, 40.74923], [-73.98819, 40.74919], [-73.98804, 40.74912], [-73.98802, 40.74912], [-73.98802, 40.74911], [-73.98801, 40.7491], [-73.98803, 40.749], [-73.98805, 40.74898], [-73.98807, 40.74896], [-73.98808, 40.74894], [-73.9881, 40.74881], [-73.98812, 40.74869], [-73.98813, 40.74863], [-73.98814, 40.74858], [-73.98817, 40.74845], [-73.9882, 40.74831], [-73.98824, 40.74811], [-73.98836, 40.74754], [-73.98839, 40.74735], [-73.98841, 40.74721], [-73.98843, 40.74713], [-73.98844, 40.74707], [-73.98849, 40.74679], [-73.98858, 40.74604], [-73.98867, 40.74582], [-73.98872, 40.74559], [-73.98877, 40.7453], [-73.9889, 40.74455], [-73.98894, 40.74435], [-73.98899, 40.74412], [-73.98903, 40.74392], [-73.98904, 40.7438], [-73.98905, 40.74368], [-73.98911, 40.74337], [-73.98915, 40.74316], [-73.98917, 40.74303], [-73.98919, 40.74294], [-73.98924, 40.74261], [-73.98924, 40.74257], [-73.98924, 40.74253], [-73.98923, 40.74252], [-73.98922, 40.7425], [-73.98902, 40.74231], [-73.98902, 40.74231], [-73.98906, 40.74225], [-73.98931, 40.7419], [-73.9894, 40.7418], [-73.98959, 40.74155], [-73.9901, 40.74087], [-73.99053, 40.74025], [-73.99096, 40.73967], [-73.99139, 40.73908], [-73.99181, 40.73849], [-73.99222, 40.73792], [-73.99267, 40.73732], [-73.99315, 40.73669], [-73.99347, 40.73624], [-73.99352, 40.73618], [-73.99363, 40.73602], [-73.99416, 40.7353], [-73.99459, 40.73467], [-73.99507, 40.73403], [-73.99552, 40.73344], [-73.99594, 40.73284], [-73.99638, 40.73225], [-73.99668, 40.73185], [-73.99698, 40.73141], [-73.99698, 40.73141], [-73.9971, 40.73147], [-73.9985, 40.73216], [-73.99863, 40.73222], [-73.99863, 40.73222], [-73.99873, 40.73211], [-73.99913, 40.73164], [-73.99962, 40.73105], [-73.99962, 40.73105], [-73.99886, 40.73067], [-73.99886, 40.73067], [-73.99903, 40.73046]]
```

Inspecting the console shows that the `D3` plot is plopping lines on top of one another over and over again, pointing to some sort of error on my part:

[image]

My question is: **where in [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/ResidentMario/13e902fd16fca628cc3fc826600bd2fe) did I screw things up, and how do I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main issues here.

Firstly, you are appending a new line to the overlay element each time the user zooms. This is the cause of the multiple lines on top of each other. The standard d3 approach is to only update the canvas when the underlying data changes, hence the better approach would be to only update the path when you enter new data. Note the use of the `selectAll` and `enter()` methods:

```
    // Paints a single sampler path.
    function paintPath(linearray) {

        // Define x and y conversions.
        var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return proj.latLngToLayerPoint(d).x})
                .y(function(d) { return proj.latLngToLayerPoint(d).y});

        var updateSelection = sel.selectAll('path').data([linearray]);
        updateSelection.enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr({
                    "class": "sample-line",
                    "d": line,
                    "fill": "transparent",
                    "stroke": "steelblue",
                    "stroke-width": 0.1,
                    "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"
                })
    }
```

The second issue is with the `latLngToPoint` function. From the documentation, this function:

> Projects geographical coordinates on a given zoom into pixel
>   coordinates

When you are zoomed out, the mapping to pixels is not very precise (hence the jagged line that you see). Because you aren't removing this line when the user zooms in, the additional lines that get appended overlay this initial jagged line, which also gets zoomed in. At a closer zoom level, the mapping to pixels more closely reflects the true coordinates, and you get a better line drawn. This explains the weird jagged overlay you are seeing.

This creates a bit of an issue, because merely calling `.enter()` is not going to update the line, as the underlying data has not changed. A simple solution (probably not perfect in terms of performance) would be to redraw the line each time the user zooms in:

```
    // Paints a single sampler path.
    function paintPath(linearray) {

        // Define x and y conversions.
        var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return proj.latLngToLayerPoint(d).x})
                .y(function(d) { return proj.latLngToLayerPoint(d).y});

        sel.selectAll('path').remove();
        var updateSelection = sel.selectAll('path').data([linearray]);
        updateSelection.enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr({
                    "class": "sample-line",
                    "d": line,
                    "fill": "transparent",
                    "stroke": "steelblue",
                    "stroke-width": 0.1,
                    "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"
                })
    }
```

The better solution may be to use the data returned from `latLngToLayerPoint` as your D3 `data` element. This way you will be able to update the line when you zoom in to a higher resolution. I will leave you to implement this.

To maintain constant line width upon zoom, you can use `"vector-effect":"non-scaling-stroke". Note the change in stroke width. This is almost something I would pull out into CSS.

```
.attr({
       "class": "sample-line",
       "d": line,
       "fill": "transparent",
       "stroke": "steelblue",
       "stroke-width": 1,
       "shape-rendering": "crispEdges",
       "vector-effect": "non-scaling-stroke"
      })
```

Edit: Ignore my comments about performance. It seems that even without removing and reappending lines (ie. just keeping the first line drawn), there is still a bit of lag when you scroll around the map. This is probably an issue on the Leaflet side.

Edit2: Note that I've also changed `paintPathSampler` to remove the second call to `paintPath`:

```
            // Paints all of the paths.
            function paintPathSampler() {
                d3.json("path_sampler.json", function (data) {
                    paintPath(data[0]);
                  //  paintPath(data[1]);
//                     paintPointPath(data[0]);

                });
            }
```

Comment: Amazing! I hope you don't mind my returning to this answer again going forward; this example gives me a motivation to finally go out and learn how selection and data binding in d3 *really* work.

As an aside, in implementing a redraw/update method would it be trivial to ask D3 to keep the lines at the same width-per-zoom level?

Comment: You can add `"vector-effect": "non-scaling-stroke"` to the line attributes to achieve this. It won't work in IE.

Comment: And yes, well worth learning how D3's selection and data binding work. It can take a while for it to click, but once it does it is incredibly useful.

Comment: Back now. Your code is slightly wrong: it paints the line 140 times, once for each pair of coordinates in the list! To solve this issue is juggled `sel.append('path').datum(linearray)` in the line-painting code (`paintPath`) and a `sel.selectAll('path').remove();` in the all lines-painting code (`paintPathSampler`). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that, I should have noticed that. I've updated my code accordingly. I've removed the `datum` call, and changed the data call from `data(linearray)` to `data([linearray])`.